# java- how to obtain/store string variables which have different charsets

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have some data in a variable of type List. Different elements in the list are encoded in different charsets. I know the charset corresponding to each element.

I want to know: how do I extract each String in its respective charset?

Also, if I have some text being entered into my Java application by a user (along with its charset), then how can I store each value in a list variable? and how can I store/retrieve such a value in a String variable?

And after the data is stored/retrieved, will the changes of charset mean that now the default charset (UTF-8) is no longer being used? If this is the case, how can I restore the default charset?

Comment: Don't understand the problem here. You can just add a string with a given charset using `list.add(new String("myString", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));`

Comment: @adarshr - ok, and how to retrieve a string of a specific charset? thanks...

Comment: Something like `list.get(20);` will get you the 20th string. If you mean retrieving a list *based* on a given charset, you'll have to quit using a plain `List` and switch to a `Map` based datastructure.

Answer (score 0):

A String is always stored (internal) as UNICODE. You only need to handle charsets if you convert bytearrays to strings or strings to bytearrays.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is to keep Strings in UTF-16 and convert to/from when doing input/output. You have Strings that were not properly converted. It may be tricky to convert them correctly now. Go back to the place when that Strings are created, and fix the input procedure.